# Is it possible to test Asp.net MVC (being developed using Visual Studio) on Local IIS Web server as the root application of a website ...?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis

I want to test my asp.net MVC project (being developed using Visual Studio) on Local IIS Web server as the root application of a destinated website rather than as a nested/child application under the root application.

Note: Normally Visual Studio forces us to create Virtual Directory under the website if we test the project  on Local IIS Web server.

Edit 1: Don't suggest me to publish it to the root application please because it is a bit tedious. I am sorry, I am lazy.

Comment: If you are lazy why testing on IIS at all? Isn't the Visual Studio's built-in web server enough for your needs?

Comment: Built-in web server runs too slow.

Comment: You don't have to ask the whole question in the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a virtual directory.  Create a separate site in IIS (may be with a different port, for ex: 8080) and point that site to your local project web folder.

Now in visual studio set project url to http://localhost:8080, and you are good to test the site at the root.

Comment: @user6130, what is "local project web folder" ?

Comment: MVC is not any different than webform when setting up the site in IIS. Go to IIS and create a site, it will ask you for the physical path of the site and you point that to the MVC root.

Comment: Should I check `Override application root URL` ?

Comment: No you don't need to, just change the project url to point to your IIS site url.  ex: http://localhost:8080

Comment: @user6130, thank you very much. It works and runs very fast :-)

Comment: @user6130, from IIS manager, should I configure permission for the local project web folder? Or it is already setup automatically?